# Way to refactor javascript code

Tags: javascript, extjs, code-readability

I am developing a sencha application from past 3 months.

Application sources contain several JS files say 20 approx with each file containing 800 - 1000 lines of code on an average. The code is completely messy. It contains atleast 20% of dead, unreachable code which is not needed.

Now the task at hand is to clean up everything and make code easier to understand and maintainable. If someone says to change some functionality I m struggling to find the right place in code where I can add changes. Being in this situation how do I approach my task at hand?

Surely looking for help with some automation tool that can ease my effort.
Thanks in advance.